# how to find max value in array assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.org 0
.code 32
.text
array : .word 10,11,12,13,14
/* how to access above array by using registers and how to find the maximum number of an array*/
/*same problem how can we solve by using ARM Directives*/
```

Comment: Please precise your question, describe what you already tried, what you expect and which result you got.

Comment: This is not the right kind of question for StackOverflow

Comment: Since I don't want to spoil the learning experience, here's a puzzle: these are the correct instruction mnemonics, in the correct order, for the shortest implementation I can think of, for which I will provide **no** other explanation; the challenge is to figure out how to fill in all the operands/labels/etc. appropriately: `adr`, `mov`, `mov`, `ldr`, `cmp`, `movgt`, `subs`, `bne`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Comment: actually i answer my question but i want to know there is any possibilty to optimize my code

Answer (score 0):

```
.org 0
.code 32
.text

_array : 
    .word 10,9,14,13,15
    .skip 512

_start : .global _start

    adr r0,_array
    ldr r5,=4
    ;ldr r3,=0
    ldr r1,[r0],#4
    mov r2,r1

loop : 
    ldr r1,[r0],#4
    cmp r2,r1
    blt loop1
    sub r5,r5,#1
    cmp r5,#0
    beq halt
    bgt loop
loop1:
    mov r2,r1
    sub r5,r5,#1
    cmp r5,#0
    beq halt
    bgt loop    

halt: b halt
```

Comment: i can get the results exactly but anyone help me there is any possibile to optmize my code